# ZeroC slide2js get wrong

Tags: node.js, ice

```
Error: spawn /home/lanceloft/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/slice2js/build/Release/slice2js ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

just do as like Official website demo,but npm install slice2js -g get wrong,

```
Error: Run "sh -c node-gyp rebuild" error, exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (/usr/lib/node_modules/cnpm/node_modules/runscript/index.js:65:21)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

but if I execution slice2js say the first error;
please help me

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: slice2js should be in /home/lanceloft/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/slice2js/build/Release/slice2js

Comment: use ubuntu 16.04 and centos7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved,Because a library file does not exist,
execute `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`